# Limit of a certain expression

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $(0,1)$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{x\to0+} f(x)=0$ and estimates
$$
|f^{(k)}(x)|\le Cx^{-k},\quad  k=0,1,2;\ x\in(0,1),
$$
hold.

*Is it true that* $$\lim_{x\to0+} xf'(x)=0?$$

Or, for function $g(x)=xf(x)$, it is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to0+} g'(x)=0$ since $g'(x)=f(x)+xf'(x)$.

Remark. If to drop the condition on derivatives for $k=2$, i.e. $|f''(x)|\le Cx^{-2}$, the statement is false as the following example shows:
Let $f(x)=x \cos \frac1x$, then$$
x f'(x)=\sin \frac{1}{x}+x \cos \frac{1}{x}
$$
does not tend to $0$. In this case,$$
f''(x)=-\frac1{x^{3}}\cos \frac{1}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is true! In order to prove this, we recall following modifacted Taylor-forumla: We have 
$$f(t) = f(x) + f'(x)(t-x) + \int_x^t (f'(s)-f'(x)) \,\mathrm{d}s$$
for $x,t\in (0,1)$. This formula can be easily checked by integration. Note that we only need that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$.

We apply this formula to $t=(1+\varepsilon)x$ in order to find
$$f'(x) x = \frac{1}{ε} \left( f((1+ε)x)-f(x) - \int_x^{(1+ε)x} (f'(s)-f'(x)) \,\mathrm{d}s \right).$$
Now, we know that $f((1+ε)x)-f(x) \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow 0+$ and fixed $ε >0$. Moreover, we can bound the integrand using$$|f'(s)-f'(x)| \leq |s-x| \sup_{h \in [x,(1+ε)x]} |f''(h)| \leq  |s-x| · Cx^{-2} \leq Cεx^{-1}.$$
Thus
$$ \frac{1}{ε}\left|\int_x^{(1+ε)x} (f'(s)-f'(x)) \,\mathrm{d}s \right| \leq \int_x^{(1+ε)x} C x^{-1} \,\mathrm{d}s \leq  Cε.$$
All togehter implies
$$\limsup_{x \rightarrow 0+} |f'(x) x| \leq Cε$$
and, since $ε>0$ is arbitary, we get already the claim.

> Inspecting the proof, we see that we only used $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0+} f(x) =0$ and $|f''(x)| \leq C x^{-2}$, and that $f$ is twice differentiable.

**Edit**: My initial formula was wrong. I have repaired the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m(x)=\sup_{y\in(0,x]}\sqrt{\big|f(y)\big|}$; this function is non-decreasing, $m(x)<\tfrac12$ for sufficiently small $x$, and $\lim_{x\to+0}\frac{f(x)}{m(x)}=0$.

Apply Taylor's formula with center $b=x$ and $a=x(1-m(x))>\tfrac{x}2$ as
$$ f(a) = f(b) - f'(b)(b-a) + \frac12f''(\xi)(b-a)^2. \\
f(a) = f(x) - f'(x)\cdot x~m(x) + \frac12f''(x)\cdot (x~m(x))^2 \\
x~f'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{m(x)} - \frac{f(a)}{m(x)} + \frac{m(x)}{2}\cdot (x/\xi)^2 \big(\xi^2f''(\xi)).
$$
On the R.H.S.each term converges to $0$: if $x\to+0$ then $a\to0$,
$\frac{f(x)}{m(x)}\to0$,
$\frac{\big|f(a)\big|}{m(x)} \le \frac{\big|f(a)\big|}{m(a)}\to0$,
$\xi^2f''(\xi)$ and $x/\xi$ are bounded and $m(x)\to0$.